# Is there any method for request object in servlets that can identify page reload event for the webpage

Tags: java, servlets, html

I need to detect the page reload event on the servlet. I was wondering if there is any method in request object that can help me to do so or if there is not.... is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you tap the "Reload" button in a browser, it specifically ignores the cache-control directives and requests a fresh copy.  Therefore you can inspect the request headers and look for an absent `If-Modified-Since` header:

```
public void doGet( final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    if ( isReloaded(request) ) handleReload( request, response );
    else handleNormal( request, response );
}

boolean isReloaded( final HttpServletRequest request )
{
    return request.getParameter("If-Modified-Since") == null;
}

/**
 * You may need to modify this function or you may not need it at all.
 * Let me know and I'll edit the solution.
 */
protected long getLastModified( final HttpServletRequest request )
{
    return new Date().getTime();
}
```

If you're behind a proxy such as Apache mod_proxy,
you may also need to set `ExpiresActive off` in the Apache files.

Also there's no way to distinguish between the **first** time someone visits a page and the "Reload" button without the use of cookies.

Cache control directives don't come into play on doPost, so the same trick won't work for doPost.

If you have a small server with a limited number of URLs, you could consider setting a cookie for every URL.  If the cookie is present it's a reload event.  If it's absent, it's a first time visit.  That would work for both `doGet` and `doPost`.

The negative is that it seems there's a maximum limit in most browsers on how many cookies you can set per domain.  For Chrome, the limit seems to be 180 cookies per domain, and 4096 bytes per cookie.

Comment: can you guide me with some code snippet for reference.